# Change color of left element Status Bar in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

(English is not my native language, PROMT translate)

[image: Left element Status Bar]

In **[Default.sublime-theme](https://github.com/cj/sublime/blob/master/Theme%20-%20Default/Default.sublime-theme)** or [**Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme**](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/blob/master/Soda%20Dark%203.sublime-theme)
 I didn't find the demanded class. I also didn't find required setting me in [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html). Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to put that first line in all of your posts - your English is in general quite good. If people don't understand something, they'll ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That default theme is out of date - [in build 3103, this new button was added](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-3101/17027/1) and the class name for it is `panel_button_control`.

To see the Default theme that is shipped with your version of ST3:

- install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control
- open the Command Palette
- type `PRV:`
- select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
- select `Theme - Default`
- select `Default.sublime-theme`
- you will see `panel_button_control` is there

Comment: Only [I don't see](https://i.gyazo.com/290317efa1b218487b76f99d44a4cde7.png) `panel_button_control` in Command Palette. Thanks.